# Powershell GUI Save File Dialog only creates the File temporarily

Tags: powershell, user-interface, savefiledialog

I tried to create a Save Button in my Powershell GUI and i found an matching script somewhere and created the Button wtih the following script

```
$SaveButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SaveButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,316)
$SaveButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$SaveButton.Text = "Save"
$SaveButton.Name = "Filter"
$SaveButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None
$SaveButton.Add_Click({

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.forms")
$dlg = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$dlg.FileName = "Document" # Default file name
$dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt" # Default file extension
$dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt" # Filter files by extension

# Show save file dialog box
$resulttest = $dlg.ShowDialog()

# Process save file dialog box results
if ($resulttest) {
  # Save document
  $filename = $dlg.FileName
  $result
}


})
$objForm.Controls.Add($SaveButton)
```

When i save my results now there is no file, but in Explorer under last used files i can see them.
But when i try to click on them he tells me the file is not existing. So i guessed he only creates the file as long as the Prozess `$SaveButton.Add_Click({}]` runs, i thought a problem i had earlyer was similar and changed all the variables to $global:(variable) but it didnt help.

Comment: In your code I don't see you're actually creating a file somewhere.. You just capture the FileName in variable `$filename` but then do nothing with it. Is whatever shoud be saved in a textbox on the form perhaps? I'm missing something like `$textBox.Text | Set-Content -Path $filename`. Also, where does varoable `$result` come from???

Comment: @Theo $result is earlier in the script and gets displayed in a text box, i will try with $result | Set-Content -Path $filename

Comment: @Theo thank you, i didnt notice that i only set the path without using it, now it works